# VBA code that changes background color of form conditionally by answer

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to use VBA (or some other solution) to conditionally change the background color of a form based off what number users enter in a numeric field. Basically, after they enter their answer to the Starter question, if they entered 1 then I want the form background to change to a specific shade of blue, and if they entered 2 then I want the form background to change to a specific shade of green. I saw a code that looks like it would be very similar to my need in another question on here, but I couldn't figure out how to make the code work, and was having trouble figuring out exactly how/where to put each module.

Some information:
The field I want it to be based off of is numeric, called Starter, and through data validation users are limited to entering 1, 2, 9, or leaving it blank. I only want the color to change if it's entered as 1 or 2.

I'm using Access 2010

the form has neither header nor footer

the code I was attempting to use and made some alterations to is the following:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
blue_yes = "15325906"
green_no = "13888226"

Dim colorThis As String

booWhatever = Me.Starter  ''Use of the variable can prevent problems

If booWhatever = 1 Then
colorThis = "blue_yes"
End If
If booWhatever = 2 Then
colorThis = "green_no"
End If
subFrm.Form.Section(acDetail).BackColor = colorThis

subFrm.Form.Repaint
End Sub
```

I've also managed, off a very different piece of code, to sort of do what I want, but the way it's working it seems to change the status of all forms, not just the one I'm currently working with, which is the goal. So for example if I enter 2 to starter, it changes the background color of every single record's form.

```
Private Sub Starter_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Starter = "1" Then Me.Detail.BackColor = vbBlue
If Me.Starter = "2" Then Me.Detail.BackColor = vbGreen
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Welp, embarrassingly I found the solution. It's not a very neat one, but it works.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim Presence As String
Presence = Nz(Me.Starter.Value, 9)
Select Case Presence
Case "1"
Me.Detail.BackColor = 15325906
Case "2"
Me.Detail.BackColor = 13888226
Case Else
Me.Detail.BackColor = vbWhite
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Starter_AfterUpdate()
Dim Presence As String
Presence = Nz(Me.Starter.Value, 9)
Select Case Presence
Case "1"
Me.Detail.BackColor = 15325906
Case "2"
Me.Detail.BackColor = 13888226
Case Else
Me.Detail.BackColor = vbWhite
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is a really old question (probably you have already solved it in a better way) but I will give it a try anyways.

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()
    Select Case Me.Text0.Text
    Case ""

    Case "1"
        Me.Detail.BackColor = 15325906
    Case "2"
        Me.Detail.BackColor = 13888226
    Case Else
        Me.Detail.BackColor = vbWhite
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** 
I tried that and it works I think now as it supposed to do. 
When you change the *text* on the text box triggers this event every time, runs the Sub, checks it's own *text* and changes the color of the form as described.

The change is that I changed the property of the field it checks. From *Value* to *Text*. We want when the event triggers to check the current text because the Value property updates when you "finish" with the textbox (after you press enter or the focus on the control is lost) and we want the change to happen the same moment we press the key changing the value and not later.

The second change and the reason we got strange patterns before is that I have added one more Case when the text is "" to do nothing on that change (empty case). Without that case when we used delete or backspace to remove the text and left the textbox empty ("") then the case else was True and it changed the background color.

I hope this is the correct answer now. Please let me know!

Comment: I used the clunky way I described above. I tried this way, and it almost works, but not consistently (I'm sure it's consistent and I just haven't figured out the pattern). When I enter 1 the first time and tab, the background stays white. Then when I go back and enter 2, it updates with the blue. But then when I go back and enter 1 again, it stays blue. When I enter 1 again (after it having just been one), then it will turn green.

Comment: No, I mean, I tried the way you gave me, and it almost works, but not perfectly. When I enter 1 the first time and tab, the background stays white. Then when I go back and enter 2, it updates with the blue. But then when I go back and enter 1 again, it stays blue. When I enter 1 again (after it having just been one), then it will turn green

Comment: Ok. I think I found my mistake. I changed my answer. Could you please check again?